# GeoTIFF reprojection to polar stereographic: Can I speed it up?

Tags: gdal, gdalwarp

For a GeoServer project I need to reproject my high resolution (~40000 pixels wide) GeoTIFF files to polar Stereographic (EPSG 3031 and EPSG 3413).
I manage to do this with `gdalwarp`, but this is very slow (>20min per file), even if I use intermediate VRT files. I tried to play with several cache configuration options of `gdalwarp`, but it does not help very much. The reprojection will be part of an operational system, so speed is important. 
Are there other tools/ways to do these reprojections? With GDAL or otherwise?

For one of my files, here is the gdalinfo output:

```
Size is 36000, 12166

Coordinate System is:

GEOGCS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["WGS_1984",
        SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
    UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]

Origin = (-180.000000000000000,82.840000000000003)

Pixel Size = (0.010000000000000,-0.010000000000000)

Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area

Image Structure Metadata:
  COMPRESSION=DEFLATE
  INTERLEAVE=BAND

Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (-180.0000000,  82.8400000) (180d 0' 0.00"W, 82d50'24.00"N)
Lower Left  (-180.0000000, -38.8200000) (180d 0' 0.00"W, 38d49'12.00"S)
Upper Right ( 180.0000000,  82.8400000) (180d 0' 0.00"E, 82d50'24.00"N)
Lower Right ( 180.0000000, -38.8200000) (180d 0' 0.00"E, 38d49'12.00"S)
Center      (   0.0000000,  22.0100000) (  0d 0' 0.01"E, 22d 0'36.00"N)

Band 1 Block=256x256 Type=Float32, ColorInterp=Gray
  NoData Value=-9999
  Overviews: 18000x6083, 9000x3042, 4500x1521, 2250x761, 1125x381, 563x191, 282x96, 141x48
```

Comment: I bet that your source GeoTIFF is not tiled. Check with gdalinfo and if I am right convert it with `gdal_translate -of GTiff -co tiled=yes -co compress=deflate input.tif output.tif` before using gdalwarp.

Comment: Thanks, but is is tiled. I added some example gdalinfo output to my question.

Comment: Pity, that would have been so simple. Do you have some test data, your own or similar, for testing?

Comment: I put two example files here for download: ftp://ftp-ae.oma.be/pub/from_Jeroen.VanGent/

Comment: This takes 6 min 15 sec with my laptop `gdalwarp -of GTiff -co tiled=yes -co compress=deflate -t_srs epsg:3031 s5p_tropomi_aai_20191202_res0.01.tiff stereo.tif` and with multiple threads about 5 min `gdalwarp -of GTiff -co tiled=yes -co compress=deflate -t_srs epsg:3031 s5p_tropomi_aai_20191202_res0.01.tiff stereo2.tif -multi -wo NUM_THREADS=ALL_CPUS`. Adjusting the memory settings of gdalwarp may give surprising results because more may not be better. Test with small steps.

Comment: Thank you! Will test it tomorrow, when back in the office.

Comment: user30184, I tried your gdalwarp command and get similar results as you. After a bit of testing I found that the culprit in my initial tests was the -wo SOURCE_EXTRA=1000 option, which I sometimes need in order to prevent gaps in the result. Lowering the value of 1000 helps and I have to find a balance there. Thanks again very much for your help!